# Is there a way to use a user inputted string as part of a method call for a method from another class

Tags: java

Starting from a user input that tells you what units a measurement is in, I would like to be able to convert it into the final units that are also given by the user input in the same way

Using a simple Java unit converter, which is used like this:

e.g To convert 1 foot to 12 inches:

```
 UnitConverter.convert(1, UnitConverter.Lengths.FEET, UnitConverter.Lengths.INCHES);
```

Let's say I get the user to input FEET as a string, and INCHES as their desired output. How can I use the string variables to call the correct method?

I've made a hashmap that connects the user input to the correct Unit:

```
int startUnitNo;
int finalUnitNo;
HashMap<Integer, String> units = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
String startUnit;
String finalUnit;

    //populate the units hashmap
        units.put(1, "KILOGRAMS");
        units.put(2, "POUNDS");
        units.put(3, "METERS");
        units.put(4, "FEET");
        units.put(5, "INCHES");
        units.put(6, "CENTIMETERS");
        units.put(7, "MILLIMETERS");
        units.put(8, "PIECE");

        //ask for the units and get the string for it
        System.out.println("Units: 1.KG  2.LB  3.M  4.FT  5.IN  6.CM  7.MM  8.PIECE");
        startUnitNo = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        startUnit = units.get(startUnitNo);

        //com.company.UnitConverter converter = new com.company.UnitConverter();

        System.out.println("Final Units: 1.KG  2.LB  3.M  4.FT  5.IN  6.CM  7.MM  8.PIECE");
        finalUnitNo = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        finalUnit = units.get(finalUnitNo);

        //if statement to check if units are different, go ahead and convert the measurement
        if (!finalUnit.trim().toLowerCase().equals(startUnit) && startUnitNo < 3 && finalUnitNo < 3)
        {

//at this point I'm stuck, I have no Idea how to use the startUnit and finalUnit string as part of the converter method
        }
```

Comment: And what have you tried?  Please post relevant code and what you have issues with.

Comment: I've added the code that sets up how to convert the values. I'm just stuck at how I could use the strings as part of the converter method. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying if the `String` is `FEET` you want to call the method for feet?  Why not just use an `if` statement compares the `String` then call the correct one for the two cases?  Or a `switch` is there are a lot of cases.  If you need to use the check in a lot of places you can then extract the `switch` to a method that takes the `String` as a parameter.

Comment: ah, smart idea. I might use a switch then. I was calculating that if I have to code 2(masses)+20(lengths) possible conversions, a bunch of if statements might not have been ideal. How many switch cases would you consider too many? What do you mean by extracting the switch to a method that takes the string parameter? Thankyou for your help

Comment: Ah, bless, that'd be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I meant by using a `switch` in a method.  You pass the `String` input you receive from the user as a parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    convertUnits("feet"); //Pass user input instead
    convertUnits("inches");
}


public static void convertUnits(String str)
{
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    switch (str) {
    case "FEET":
        System.out.println("Feet was called."); //Put what logic you need done in here
    break;
    case "INCHES":
        System.out.println("Inches was called.");
    break;
    case "MILLIMETERS":
        System.out.println("Millimeters was called.");
    break;
    //default:
    //etc...
    }
}
```

`str.toUpperCase()` is used to ignore case sensitivity on user input.

This method allows easy reuse of the code whenever you need to convert the unit that was given.  Instead of passing a hardcoded `String`, you can pass the user input.  Insert any logic or code you need where the `print` statements are in the `convertUnits` method and add any other `cases` you need, or a `default`.

I don't think there is really anything considered *too* much in a `switch`, it just depends on what you need.

**EDIT:**

To help you along a little more, if you want to be able to convert, from and to any units passed, you can use two methods with a switch in each like so:

```
public static final String FEET = "FROMFEET";
public static final String INCHES = "INCHES";
public static final String MILLIMETERS = "MILLIMETERS";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkUnits("feet","inches", 2);
    checkUnits("inches","feet", 1);
}


public static void checkUnits(String from, String to, int units)
{
    from = from.toUpperCase();
    switch (from) {
    case "FEET":
        convertUnits(FEET,to, units);
    break;
    case "INCHES":
        convertUnits(INCHES,to, units);
    break;
    case "MILLIMETERS":
        convertUnits(MILLIMETERS,to, units);
    break;
    //default:
    //etc...
    }
}

public static void convertUnits(String from, String to, int units)
{
    to = to.toUpperCase();
    switch (to) {
    case "FEET":
        System.out.println("FROM: " + from + " to: " + to + " Units: " + units);
    break;
    case "INCHES":
        System.out.println("FROM: " + from + " to: " + to + " Units: " + units);
    break;
    case "MILLIMETERS":
        System.out.println("FROM: " + from + " to: " + to + " Units: " + units);
    break;
    //default:
    //etc...
    }
}
```

But instead of passing the `public static final String` I used as examples to `convertUnits`, you can pass the actual value you need to use in the outside method that converts the units (like the `UnitConverter.Lengths.FEET`).  And instead of the `print` statements in `convertUnits`, you call that libraries convert method.  This would allow you to convert any unit you want *to* any unit you want fairly easily.

It is basically a nested `switch` statement, but it is a lot cleaner to place it into two methods.

Comment: Ah, got it. Yeah, i'll code the 22 cases individually then with a switch. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: @Sephos Not sure if this will assist you more, but I added a more specific way to use this for your case, if you want convert units from 2 user inputted `String`s instead of 1.